# Are they (GCC) support default args in function template or not:

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

In here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/
My first question:
1. How is it possible (see the news column) that
News
**October 1**, 2010
GCC 4.4.5 has been released.
**July 31**, 2010
GCC 4.5.1 has been released.
**May 22**, 2010
GCC 4.3.5 has been released.
**April 29**, 2010
GCC 4.4.4 has been released.
**April 14**, 2010
GCC 4.5.0 has been released.
According to this list newer version (4.5.0) was released earlier than older version 4.4.5.
What am I suppose to read this to make a sense out of it?
Second Q:
2. In here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
They're saying that dflt tmp args in fnc are supported by their 4.4 ver. I run 4.4.1 ver and when I try to compile this:

```
#include <vector>

template<class Key, class CollT = std::vector>
CollT* delete_(Key kValue)
{
    return new CollT;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error.
So what's going on?

Comment: I think this belongs to StackOverflow.

Comment: The second part needs to be made a separate question and belongs on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). First part looks on-topic here to me.

Comment: -1 for having been here long enough to have asked over 200 questions but still being too lazy to actually spell out the words in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1:

4.5 and 4.4 are different branches of development. It happens with many projects. Python, for instance, had version 3.0, currently has 3.1, but still supports 2.6/2.7 branch. (and also backports some features from 3.x to 2.x)

Answer 2:

I think you should not ask multiple (unrelated?) questions at once. I know the answer for the first, but not for the second.

Comment: +1 for nice answer to 1. Basically, version 4.5 brings new features while version 4.4 is in bugfix phase.

Comment: @AndrejKo but shouldn't it be that 4.5 has everything what 4.4 has plus extra?

Comment: Not always. Sometimes we need to make some major changes, and some bugs might show up, or maybe it breaks some other tool that was expecting the old format/behavior. That's a good reason to keep supporting the older version for some time. In addition, Python 3.x actually removed a few features from 2.x series, so not always the next version has everything that the previous one had.

Comment: but those features removed in Python 3.x which are in 2.x were probably depracated. That's normal practice. But having new feature in older version and not having it in newer version is just illogical.

Answer (score 1):

std::vector is not a type without a template argument. This means that you cannot set it as the default argument to a template parameter.

Comment: he could give it a template argument though. e.g. `template<class Key,class CollT = std::vector<Key> >`